# THREE.Sprite not working on my Android device

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to render images with THREE.Sprite on my Android phone but the images does not show up. Using the remote debugger of Chrome browser from Mac i'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vertexAttribDivisorANGLE' of null
    at THREE.WebGLState.enableAttribute (three.min.js:728)
    at THREE.SpritePlugin.render (three.min.js:752)
    at THREE.WebGLRenderer.render (three.min.js:663)
    at animate (app.js:1241)
enableAttribute @   three.min.js:728
render  @   three.min.js:752
render  @   three.min.js:663
animate @   app.js:1241
requestAnimationFrame (async)
```

Device info:

- Chrome application version: 56.0.2924.87
- Operating system: Android 4.1.2: GT-l8190L Build/JZO54K

The piece of code i'm using:

```
const createSprite = (spriteMap, scaleUnit = 1) => {
  const material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: spriteMap });
  const sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
  const width = material.map.image.width * scaleUnit;
  const height = material.map.image.height * scaleUnit;
  sprite.scale.set(width, height, 1);
  return sprite;
};

// To load my textures:
const loadComponents = (components, callback) => {
  const loadFabricImages = (images, loaded, objs) => {
    if (images.length) {
      fabric.Image.fromURL(images.shift(), (img) => {
        loaded.push(img);
        objs[img._element.getAttribute('src').split('/').pop().split('.').shift()] = img;
        loadFabricImages(images, loaded, objs);
      });
    } else {
      callback(loaded, objs);
    }
  };

  loadFabricImages(components, [], {});
};

loadComponents(['img1.png', 'img2.png'], (textures) => {
    const sprite = createSprite(textures[0], 0.55);
});
```

It works pretty good on other devices and browsers.

Is there any solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.